# Behavior of libsocket create_inet_server_socket and accept_inet_stream_socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, server

I am writing a small C server to receive data from a ESP8266 module (small wireless module). Specifically, I am curious about what I should be checking to look for a connection. Here is my code:

```
/*
 * main.c
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 9, 2015
 *      Author: matthew
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <libsocket/libinetsocket.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int* async_socket_rcv(int clientfd);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socketfd, clientfd;

    pthread_t thread;

    socketfd = create_inet_server_socket("0.0.0.0", "5677", LIBSOCKET_TCP, LIBSOCKET_IPv4, 0);

    while(1)
    {

        clientfd = accept_inet_stream_socket(socketfd,0,0,0,0,0,0);

        if(clientfd >= 0 ){

            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, async_socket_rcv, clientfd);
        }

    }

}

int* async_socket_rcv(int clientfd)
{
    char* buf = calloc(16,1);
    pthread_t thread_id = pthread_self();

    printf("Thread created");

    while(clientfd > 0){

        read(clientfd, buf, 15);
        printf("%s\n", buf);

    }

    close(clientfd);

    return 0;

}
```

As you can see, I am currently looking to see if accept_inet_stream_socket return anything other than an error, but this only seems to work if data is sent over the established connection. I would like my code to start a thread as soon as a connection is made, and hand off all handling of the connection to that thread regardless of whether or not data was sent.

I case that was not clear, let me break it down.

What is currently happening:

Start server > connect to server > nothing happens > send a string to server > server outputs "thread started" and the string sent.

What I want is:

Start server > connect to server > server says "thread started" > send a string to server > server outputs the string sent

Also if you guys could just review my code and let me know if you see any blatant errors or illogical things. I am learning sockets and threads at the same time :)

FYI, i searched far and wide for the answer before posting, namely here: [Docs](http://lbo.spheniscida.de/doc/libsocket/doxygen/html/group__libinetsocket.html#gac85fdb9dc1530a93835e527ae0002652)

Comment: Doesn't your compiler complain about the blatantly incorrect function prototype of the function pointer you want to pass to `pthread_create()`?

Comment: no.. What's wrong with it?

Comment: `man pthread_create: int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);`. The function you pass to `pthread_create()` is not supposed to take an `int` as a argument.

Comment: Hint: If you add `setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0)` to the start of `main()`, your problem will miraculously vanish...

Comment: Are you talking about the return type of async_socket_rcv?  Also,  the setvbuf is for enabling blocking when waiting for a connection?

Comment: I was talking about the *argument* `async_socket_rcv()` takes, but now that you mention it, yes, the return type is also wrong. And no, `setvbuf(stdout, ...)` doesn't affect your socket. Why would it?

Comment: Clientfd is a file descriptor,  so is int should be fine. "File descriptors are represented as objects of type int" from http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-File-Descriptors.html

Comment: Sure, you can pass an `int` to `int *async_socket_rcv(int)`. That's fine. You *can't* pass a `int *(*)(int)` to `pthread_create()` without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh I see.  So passing the file descriptor to async_socket_rcv THROUGH pthread_create is incorrect.  How do I pass a file descriptor then?

Comment: You take the address of the file-descriptor `int *fdpointer = &clientfd`, cast the `int *` to `void *` and pass the `void *` to `pthread_create()`, along with the function-pointer `void *(*foo)(void*)`, and in `foo()`, you cast back to `int *`. What did you expect? Some grand revelation?

Comment: "*You take the address of the file-descriptor*" this might very well introduce a race, if not a new file descriptor instance is created for any call to `accept_inet_stream_socket()`. @EOF So for passing an  `int` I propose the misuse the `void`-pointer as `int`, assuming the size of `void*` is greater or equal to the size of an `int`.

Comment: You want to check the result of `read()` in *any* case.

Comment: @alk: This code is running `pthread_create()` in a tight loop without `pthread_join()`, with default pthread attributes (joinable threads), with no error handling on thread creation failure (leaking file-descriptors in that case). I'd say your proposal doesn't really improve things all that much...

Comment: So let's advise the OP to put a `pthread_detach()` as 1st call into the thread function.